# Can false sharing lead to wrong results?

Tags: c++, c, caching, parallel-processing, openmp

As I know, false sharing occurs when two cpu cores access different parts of a single memory block. In this case, the L1 caches in each core contains different values.

What is the effect of false sharing? Do commodity CPUs always detect a false sharing? Can it lead to something like a race condition (persisting different cache versions in the memory)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

False sharing occurs when one core modifies some data, and another reads some unrelated data that happens to lie in the same cache line. The modification forces the second core to reload the whole cache line, even though the data it's using is unchanged.

This won't cause any incorrect behaviour unless the cache is horribly broken. But it can have a large performance impact, as cached data is unnecessarily fetched from higher level caches.

Comment: Thank you! How about multi-processor systems (multiple processors on a single motherboard)? Do they also have a cache-coherence mechanism?

Comment: @Ali: They might, though it's less likely than with multiple cores on a single chip. You'll have to read the documentations for the particular system you're using.

Comment: @Ali: It is very hard to find a general-purpose non-cache-coherent system nowadays, especially in the x86 world. Some vendors are even building multiboard cache-coherent systems by routing the HT/QPI links externally.