# Why does false sharing in caches not lead to wrong results?

Tags: multithreading, caching, concurrency

Kind of an extension to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610284/can-false-sharing-lead-to-wrong-results). How does the computer architecture work around two threads writing simultaneously to cache lines that map very close in physical memory? It seems like there could be a race condition where two threads issue a write to the same cache line at the exact same clock cycle. Can both succesfully write before they can mark the other cache's line as stale? How does this get resolved to functionally be correct?

Comment: What you want to look into is how the `MESI` cache coherency protocol works

Answer (score 2):

You should look into cache coherency protocols such as MESI and its extensions MOESI and MESIF.

In these protocols, each cacheline is essentially a state machine, transitioning from one state to the next based on what its own processor is doing as well as what messages it snoops on the bus. The cache controllers monitor the memory bus transactions and update the cachelines' states accordingly, hence the name "snoopy cache".

In MESI, a cacheline can have four states: **Modified**, **Exclusive**, **Shared** and **Invalid**.

We can walk through your example where two cores want to write to the same cacheline and see from a very high-level perspective why this protocol won't lead to incorrect results.

Assume that both cores begin with not having the cacheline and that they first read the cacheline before modifying it.

1) Core 1 wants to read the cacheline, so it broadcasts a *BusRd*, receives the cacheline from memory and transitions to **Exclusive**.

2) Core 2 also wants to read the cacheline so it broadcasts a *BusRd*. Core 1 responds with the cacheline in a *FlushOpt* and both cores transition to **Shared**.

3) Core 1 wants to write to the cacheline, so it broadcasts a *BusUpgr* and transitions to **Modified**. Core 2 sees the *BusUpgr* and transitions to **Invalid**.

4) Core 2 wants to write to the cacheline but it's **Invalid** so it issues a *BusRdX* and transitions to **Modified**. Core 1 snoops the *BusRdX* and broadcasts a *Flush* before transitioning to **Invalid**. The *Flush* is observed by Core 2 and the memory controller which writes the value back to memory.

Since a write operation on one core invalidates the cacheline copies on the other cores, the cacheline will have to be reobtained with the latest value. Thus, no race condition. :)